# Get last generated id asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I have 2 Tables in one Database (Table1 and Table2). What I want to do is to get the last generated ID (which is primary key) from the first table (Table1) and add it to another table (Table2).

[image]

[image]

For example. The Last generated ID from Table1, column NRRENDOR is 25 (I have deleted the rows that's why it shows 22, it is primary key). If I add a row to Table1 it will generate number 26 on column NRRENDOR (First picture). But when number 26 is added to column NRRENDOR from Table 1, I want it to be added to Table2, column NRD too (Second Picture).

Comment: Could you show the code you tried? Do you want use a Linq query?

Comment: mysql,sql,sql-server,sql-server-2012 ??????????

Comment: It is asp.net so it is sql server. @Inanikian as soon as get in pc i will post the code.

Comment: @aldoblack Using asp.net does not imply SQL Server.  You can use practically any data source with asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sql-query like the one below after inserting the new element to the first table.

```
Insert into table2 (id) values(Select top 1 ID from table1 order by id desc)
```

This should work in sql-server 2008 and newer.

Comment: NRRENDOR id Auto Identity "[NRRENDOR] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL," so it auto increments itself. I tried it with SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL Reference Manual, [20.6.14.3 How to Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
INSERT INTO NRRENDOR (auto, field) VALUES(NULL, 'value');
```

generate ID by inserting NULL

```
INSERT INTO NRD (id, field) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'value');
```

use ID in second table.

Or you can get the last insert id manually executing the following query immediately after the INSERT into NRRENDOR

```
SELECT last_insert_id()
```

and use it later in your second INSERT query for NRD.

Comment: NRRENDOR id Auto Identity "[NRRENDOR] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL," so it auto increments itself. I tried it with SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is for MSSQL not for MySQL but the solution is the same for both.

Comment: I am using MSSQL not mysql